# Threads in C interrupt each other

Tags: c, pthreads

So i have a global variable called counter and i run 4 threads which increment in million times but the result i am getting at the end does not even reach 2 million.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int nthread;
int counter=0;
void *f(void *arg)
{
    int i = *(int *)arg;
    int *p;
   for (int c = 0; c < 1000000; c++)
   {
       counter++;
   }

    printf(" I am thread %d (out of %d),tid =% ld\n", i, nthread, pthread_self());
    p = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = i * 2;
    pthread_exit(p); // return p
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t *tid;
    int e, i, *ti;
    nthread = 4;
    tid = malloc(nthread * sizeof(pthread_t));
    ti = malloc(nthread * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < nthread; i++)
    {
        ti[i] = i;
        if ((e = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, f, &ti[i])) != 0)
            send_error(e, " pthread_create ");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < nthread; i++)
    {
        void *r;
        if ((e = pthread_join(tid[i], &r)) != 0)
            send_error(e, " pthread_join ");
        printf(" Return of thread %d = %d\n", i, *(int *)r);
        free(r);
    }
    printf("counter is %d\n",counter);
    free(tid);
    free(ti);
}
```

What causes this and how i can fix this?
PS:if your code not compile replace send_error with printfs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pthreads standards is very clear that you may not access an object in one thread while another thread is, or might be, modifying it. Your code violates this rule.

There are many reasons for this rule, but the most obvious is this:

```
for (int c = 0; c < 1000000; c++)
{
    counter++;
}
```

You want your compiler to optimize code like this. You want it to keep `counter` in a register or even eliminate the loop if it can. But without the requirement that you avoid threads overlapping modifications and accesses to the same object, the compiler would have to somehow prove that no other code in any other thread could touch `counter` while this code was running.

That would result in a huge amount of valuable optimizations being impossible on the 99% of code that doesn't share objects across threads just because the compiler can't prove that accesses might overlap.

It makes much more sense to require code that *does* have overlapping object access to clearly indicate that they do. And every threading standard provides good ways to do this, including pthreads.

You can use any method to prevent this problem that you like. Using a mutex is the simplest and definitely the one you should learn first.

Comment: Would a mutex alone be sufficient, or would `counter` also need to be `volatile`-qualified?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons A mutex is sufficient. Any platform that required `counter` to be qualified `volatile` would be violating the pthreads standard. The mutex ensures that it's impossible for one thread to access the object while another thread might be modifying it, so you've met the requirement.

Comment: My concern isn't about simultaneous access so much as possibly optimizing out load  operations.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons You don't have to think about that. You're coding in C, not assembly. You just have to follow the C rules and the pthreads rules and then the compiler is not allowed to make optimizations that break your code because that would be it violating the standards. The standard says you cannot access the object in one thread while another thread is or might be modifying it. The mutex ensures you don't do that. Now the compiler may not make an optimization that changes the code's behavior just as it can't optimize your code by eliminating its output.

Comment: If you didn't ever have to worry about optimization of loads and stores, the `volatile` qualifier wouldn't exist.  If not informed otherwise, the compiler can choose not to load a variable from memory to a register and write back from the register out to memory on every read/write to the variable.  Performing such IO on every single operation would be rather inefficient and defeat the purpose of registers, so the compiler will generally prefer to work with what is already in a register.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons The compiler can only perform optimizations that don't break code that complies with the relevant standards otherwise the compiler does't comply with the relevant standards. I can't really explain in just a comment what's wrong with the rest of your statement and it would be confusing to people trying to learn how to use threads correctly.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: David Schwartz is correct.  In this case, POSIX says that `pthread_mutex_lock()` is one of the functions that "synchronises memory", so in practice a compiler knows that it cannot cache a variable whose address has escaped across such a function call.

Comment: @caf Thank you, that was the type of answer I was looking for.